# apa102 LED Brightness Control

Tags: python, led, google-assistant-sdk

I am working on integrating tinue's APA102 LED python code (https://github.com/tinue/APA102_Pi) into the google assistant SDK on Raspberry Pi to control a strip of LED. I am able to turn the lights on and off, and change the color, but when it comes to changing brightness setting, I am having trouble. I can start by saying "set brightness to 1%" and it shows a change in `global_brightness` from the old value to the new via `print` function. When I the say to turn red, it turns a dim red. I can increase brightness increments a few times, but if I try to increase, for example, from 20 to 100% and then say turn red, it actually gets dimmer. I thought it may have something to do with the `MAX_BRIGHTNESS` being set to `31`. But a change from something like `40` to `50`, it still gets brighter.

```
import apa102

strip = apa102.APA102(num_led=150, global_brightness=20, mosi = 10, sclk = 11,
                              order='rgb')
strip.clear_strip()

if event.type == EventType.ON_DEVICE_ACTION:
    for command, params in process_device_actions(event, device_id):
        print('Do command', command, 'with params', str(params))
        if command == "action.devices.commands.BrightnessAbsolute":
            if params['brightness']:
                strip.clear_strip()
                print ('Global brightness is ', strip.global_brightness)
                strip.global_brightness = params['brightness']
                print ('The Brightness is', strip.global_brightness)

        if command == "action.devices.commands.ColorAbsolute":
            if params['color']:
                if LEDOnOff == "Off":
                    LEDOnOff = "On"
                strip.clear_strip()
                print('The color is ', params['color'].get('name'), '.')
                for led in range(strip.num_led):
                    strip.set_pixel_rgb(led, 
                    params['color'].get('spectrumRGB')) # make desired 
                    color
                strip.show()
```

Comment: Looking at the `set_pixel` method, it seems like brightness is configured as a percentage between 0-100. https://github.com/tinue/APA102_Pi/blob/75b964bd494614c85682e94b4063803d48083621/driver/apa102.py#L144